# Spring security 6.0 - oauth2Login with MS Azure and CSRF token - how to login there in Postman?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, csrf

I'm beginner in Spring Security configuration and my purpose is set 2 things:

1. CSRF token
2. Authorization by Microsoft Azure

Firstly I've added oauth client in properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/${id}/v2.0
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-dev.provider=azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-dev.client-id=${clientId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-dev.client-secret=${secret}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-dev.scope=openid,email,profile
```

And all my GET endpoints started proxy my requests to Microsoft Login page -> after login all GET endpoints are available.

So I created security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/azure-dev").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/logout").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers( "/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
                .logout(l -> l
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")))
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Option `withHttpOnlyFalse` should add CSRF token to headers automatically, but I couldn't find it in GET requests, but it probably will be add only to POST/PUT/DELETE requests.
Then I tried to send some requests from Postman, but it's secured under Microsoft Azure login, and response is always:

```
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    (...)
```

So it's HTML to login page, but I can't open it, or handle (in browser after log in one time - I have access all the time to all requests). Again, I can't find any header/cookie which auth me in browser (to paste it in postman).

0. Where is this oAuth2 key, after login to Microsoft in Browser? I want to copy it to postman (I even tried to get it from `OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient` with `authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()`, and there was value, but this token doesn't work in postman -> it still returns microsoft HTML page).
1. Is spring security configured correctly in your opinion?
2. I'm wondering how to auth with this login page and csrf tokens from frontend, if I can't find any tokens in browser? Should I create some special endpoint (in Spring app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to OAuth2 clients are authorized with session cookie, not `Bearer` authorization header. There are options to catch Chrome cookies in Postman. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNDSEZF5IpA) for instance explains how.

As just stated, OAuth2 clients are stateful. REST APIs are better configured as stateless resource server: no session (nor CSRF protection), and requests authorized with `Bearer` access token in `Authorization` header.

OAuth2 resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients, but it is not recommended any more to configure mobile or Javascript based (Angular, Vue, React, etc.) application as ("public") OAuth2 clients. An option in the case of such front-ends is to add a thin layer (a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend) configured as a ("confidential") OAuth2 client and replacing session cookies with access tokens before forwarding a request from a browser (or native app) to resource server(s). `speing-cloud-gateway` can be configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay=` filter for that purpose. Of course, such a BFF is stateful and must be protected against CSRF.

If you have such a system, you have the choice to query directly the resource server with an access token (OAuth2 in Postman authorization tab) or to go through the BFF with a cookie for an already authorized session.

Don't search CSRF token in the headers of the responses you get from your server. It will be in a cookie, but **provided that the required filter is configured**: `csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())` as you configured [is not enough anymore in Spring Security 6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript). The CSRF token should be in a header of requests you send to the backend. So **cookie in responses** from the backend to the frontend, **header in queries** from frontend to backend (`POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` only).

If that can be of any help, I wrote [a tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) with an Angular app, a Spring resource server, and `spring-cloud-gateway` configured as BFF in-between. But be aware that it is using an additional [starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) to make Spring Security configuration simpler. You'll find tutorials to write the configuration without my starter for a [reactive client](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-client) (gateway) and [servlet](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server) (or [reactive](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-resource-server)) resource server in the same repo.